# un-reset css properties when I used css reset?

Tags: html, css, ckeditor, css-reset

I use CKEditor for my text editor, when client edit a text with CKEditor and change the font color, font size and ... I store the HTML code in my database and there is no problem.

but when I want to show the HTML Code in my page, the style will reset so many html tags not work, like font size or font color and ...

I use Eric Meyer’s “Reset CSS” 2.0 :
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

this is CKEditor WYSIWYG screenshot :
[image]

This is CKEditor HTML Code :
[image]

And this is result :

[image]

and this is firebug screen shot for this layer style :
[image]

I need to un-reset the CSS for this layer, is it possible ?

Comment: Try http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: So if the problem is the reset, it seems logical that the answer would be to not use the reset.

Comment: Hey **MajAfy**, have you solved this problem ? Cause i have same problem, and i too use `Eric Meyer’s “Reset CSS” 2.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider using http://binarystash.blogspot.com/2014/01/unresetcss.html. It restores default HTML styles removed by Eric Meyer's reset.css.

Comment: link is broken :(

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with the CSS [`:not`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp) selector, by resetting all the elements that are `not` within the WSYIWYG Editor code.

Or, if you have control over the styles, you could an `!important` declaration on the editor styles.